# Estimate $f_x$ of this function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

I am given this contour map of a certain function, and I need to estimate the partial derivative $f_x(0.5,1)$. Now, I understand $f_x$ as the rate of change of this function in the x-axis direction. Maybe I can use directional derivatives to sort of calculate this? I will need a guiding hand here.

[image]

Comment: Stand at a point $(x,y)$ and look left and right, i.e. look at the line from $(x-1,y)$ to $(x+1,y)$ for example . The closer the contour lines are, the greater $|f_x$| is (and you'll need to consider the sign of $f_x$ too). Can you see how to make that statement more precise? For example, I might estimate $f_x(1.5,2)\approx 3.5$ and $f_x(1.5,-1.5)\approx 0$.

Comment: Are you able to (approximately) sketch the single-variable function $f(x,1)$? (at least get the points where the height is an integer and draw a plausible curve through those points)?

Comment: I direction $(2,1)$ the derivative should be close to zero. Next you can try to find the  line going through $x = (0.5,1)$ whose intersection points with the contours of $-2$ and $0$ have equal distance from $x$. Then the derivative in this direction should be close to $1$ (or $-1$). Then you can find $f_x$ by a linear combination of those two.